# Where is my exposed root of my webpage in the directory structure of Azure console?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a new .NET based web application named *shabang* using the web client and it displays the default woohoo-page when I browse to *shabang.azurewebsites.net*. Then, I discovered that there's a console in the web client and when I use it, I can see a directory structure including my login name, home directory etc. However, I can't find the files being served and, since I can see a web page being rendered when browsing, I'm certain they are there, somewhere.

Where is the (or equivalent of) *wwwroot*?

I've googled it but it's a bit hard to word what I'm asking in a way that Google will understand. Just a bunch of guides that are way too advanced to distill the information from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it is d:\home\site\wwwroot. It can also be modified using the Azure Portal.

Note that you should use the Kudu Console to see it. e.g. https://shabang.scm.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Is it a hidden directory or something? In my *home*, I only have a directory with my first name and in there something called clouddrive. According to the Kudu Console (thanks for the link BTW) , Site folder is *d:\home*. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's strange that you wouldn't have a site folder under D:\home. If you share the name of an app in that state, I can take a look in a couple hours.

Comment: Based on your reassertion I just located the folder. It appears that the Bashy thing in the web portal **doesn't** list the folder but when using the PowerShelly thing in Kudu, it **does**. That was a major WTF... Now, I have a bunch of follow-up questions but those aren't covered by this topic, so +1 for the Kudu-hint and accepted as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I see you were probably in the general cloud console in the portal, which doesn't relate to any specific app. It's they're too run CLI commands against your subscription in general.